# JQuery 2.1.0 + Bootstrap 2.3.2 : autocomplete not showing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I've upgraded my ASP.NET MVC project with Bootstrap 2.3.2 and jQuery (Core: 1.7.1.1, UI: 1.8.20.1, Validation 1.9.0.1, ...) to the latest available by NuGet (2.0.1, and dependent ones).

Now the autocomplete DIV doesn't show up, but the data are retrieved by ajax successfully.

The browser is the latest release of Chrome.

Could somebody help me?

Thank you!
Antonio